# How to use linear-gradient with letter-spacing?

Tags: css, linear-gradients, letter-spacing

Is any way to combine `linear-gradient` and `letter-spacing` in fonts? The problem is that I cut a piece of the letter "B".

Linking JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net//ft7uL29g/1/

Comment: Try to better describe your problem///

Comment: I want to make a logo using `<h2>WB</h2>`, that's why I used negative `letter-spacing` in CSS, but as you can see the "B" is beheaded because I used `linear-gradient`. If there is no `letter-spacing` everything is ok.

Comment: Add some padding to your `<h2>` element: `padding: 0 10vh;`

Comment: Love u so much, thanks <3